# What is the most optimized method to loop through this code?

Tags: performance, loops, python-2.7, while-loop

stocks is a dict():

```
stocks[0]: [u'portfolio1', u'Active']
stocks[1]: [u'portfolio2', u'Active']
stocks[2]: [u'portfolio3', u'Inactive']
```

I am trying to check the status of the portfolio which is stocks[0][1], stocks[1][1] and stocks[2][1] and create a list of elements containing only the active portfolio.

And, I am using a counter to do the iteration which seems to be a very slow process. What is the most efficient method to loop through this code?

```
a = 0
test = {}
while a <= 500:
    try:
        if stocks[a][1] == 'Active':
            test[a] = stocks[a][0]
            print test[a]
            a +=1
        else:
            pass
            a +=1
    except KeyError:
        break

test = list(test.values())
test = str(','.join(test)).split(',')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could try is instead of using a counter is to iterate through the dictionary values themselves, returning only those portfolios with a status of `Active`. When you find yourself needing to check all of the items in a particular data structure, it is usually easiest to iterate over the structure itself instead of using a counter (i.e. saying `for item in iterable` instead of `for x in range(len(iterable)): iterable[x]`):

```
In [1]: stocks = {
   ...:     0: [u'portfolio1', u'Active'],
   ...:     1: [u'portfolio2', u'Active'],
   ...:     2: [u'portfolio3', u'Inactive']
   ...: }

In [2]: actives = [x[0] for x in stocks.itervalues() if x[1] == 'Active']

In [3]: actives
Out[3]: [u'portfolio1', u'portfolio2']
```

`actives` in this cause is generated using a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) that iterates through the values of the `stocks` dictionary and returns only those where `x[1]` (the status, in your case) is equal to `Active`.